# selenium & chrome 78 failing basic authentication

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, basic-authentication

In a C# program, just installed chromedriver 78.0.3904.70: Loading URLs protected by Basic Authentication is now failing.

Before chromedriver 78: Setting driver.Url = [basic-auth-url] would cause Chrome to display its Basic Auth dialog, and my C# program would block until the dialog was closed. This required manual user intervention to fill the dialog, but I could live with that.

Now, with chromedriver 78:

1. Before setting driver.Url, its value is "data:,". This is normal.
2. Call driver.Url = [basic-auth-url].
3. No exception, but still, driver.Url == "data:,". The call to set driver.Url just didn't have any effect.

When the program calls driver.Url = [basic-auth-url], Chrome may display its Basic Auth dialog and then immediately hide it; I saw this once, but if it happens all the time it's too fast to see.

Ideas or workarounds? Thanks!

Comment: I would try using driver.get... same result?

Comment: I think this may be related to this: https://kb.netgear.com/000061261/Google-Chrome-77-is-blocking-access-to-NETGEAR-login-pages-what-do-I-do  Try setting "http-auth-committed-interstitials" to false or 0 in your ChromeOptions. I also wonder if just sending a refresh might help.  driver.navigate.refresh...

Comment: "I would try using driver.get... same result?": Thanks, but this is C#. I don't believe there is a driver.get() method.

Comment: "Try setting "http-auth-committed-interstitials" to false or 0 in your ChromeOptions.": Thanks, nice lead, but I can't find a way to set an experimental flag like http-auth-committed-interstitials in ChromeOptions in C#.

Comment: I use Java for Selenium mostly, so I'm not sure, but try something like "options.AddAdditionalCapability("http-auth-committed-interstitials", 0);  In Java you use a HashMap<String, Object> for setexperimental..., so maybe you use a Dictionary in C#?

Comment: "try something like "options.AddAdditionalCapability("http-auth-committed-interstitials", 0);": Thanks, tried that, it gives an "unrecognized capability" error.

Comment: is  options.setExperimentalOption() an available method in C#?

Comment: "is options.setExperimentalOption() an available method in C#?" No.

Comment: ok...  maybe try with "--http-auth-committed-interstitials" instead... and value is probably more likely to be false.  This seems like it would also work as a flag for launching the executable so you could try passing it in the path to Chrome.   Another option might be to pass the login values in the URL.  
  so " https://username:password@url... "

Comment: maybe try options.addArguments("--http-auth-committed-interstitials-disable");  That should be an arg passed to Chrome...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I logged a bug and got agreement that it's a bug, should be fixed in version 80. See https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=3209 .

It *does* appear to have something to do with "committed interstitials" as @pcalkins proposes in the comments, but I couldn't find a way to verifiably set Chrome's http-auth-committed-interstitials flag in C#.