# Selenium Chrome 78 issue with basic authentication

Tags: selenium

[Navigate request cancelled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfxnI.png)

I am using Selenium 3.141.59 with chrome 78 (with Java). Navigate request gets cancelled and the basic authentication popup disappears hence I am not able to login to my application on the tests. This was working fine previously until I have upgraded Chrome from 76 to 78.

Chrome driver version: 78.0.3904.70

```
WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
options.addArguments("test-type");
options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.navigate().to("application url");
```

Comment: what's the question?

Comment: The tests fail because they are not able to get the basic authentication popup (hence can't login).

Comment: do you have any url that we can use to reproduce the issue and see what's happening?

Comment: didi you also update your chrome webdriver?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't share the url as its an internal application.

Comment: Webdriver manager uses the latest version of chromedriver (78.0.3904.70)

Comment: None of the solutions suggested above work. As mentioned in my original post this was working fine until the chrome version got upgraded to 78. Can someone please reopen this post

Comment: I have created a new post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58627017/selenium-chrome-78-issue-with-basic-authentication-popup) as this was closed without a working solution.

Comment: you need to make sure the drivers you are using and the browsers you are using are compatible. Upgrading the browser and everything stopping working tells all. Fix your browser version in place via docker or similar.

Comment: @AjayPolsani Do not put additional information in comments as that tends to get lost. Edit your original post with new information. Clearly list the versions of Selenium, Chrome Browser, and Chrome Driver.

Comment: I have added the chromedriver version details to the original post

Comment: Same problem for me in C#: Chromedriver 78, calling driver.Url = "[basic-auth-url]" just fails to go to the requested URL, no exception, no Basic Auth dialog (except perhaps a shown-for-an-instant-and-immediately-disappearing one) in the browser.

Comment: Of course this is *not* a duplicate as @DebanjanB marked it;  I confirmed it's a bug. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58616471/selenium-chrome-78-failing-basic-authentication .

Comment: @Conrad Albrecht thanks for the confirmation, will keep an eye on the bug :)